# Need to read the variable in file and write in other file using python. File type is text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. trying to write a program to read a file1 and write in file2

Ex: file1 contents

```
a=value1
b=value2
c=dddd.eeeee.fffff
d=value4
```

need to fetch the value of variable c and write in file2

```
file2 contents
  (suiteName: "aaaa.bbbb.ccc")
```

i need to replace the value of suiteNmae: "aaaa.bbbb.ccc" with c i.e, file 2 suitename should replace with c value suiteName: dddd.eeeee.fffff

This should be done using python file2 other values should not be changed

```
import os
import sys
import csv

file_path = "C:/Users/file1"
replace_file_path = "C:/Users/file2"


def get_c(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        fileone = csv.reader(f,delimiter='=')
        for row in fileone:
            if row[0] == 'c':
                return row[1]

 def get_suiteName(file_name):
     with open(file_name, 'r') as f1:
         filetwo = csv.reader(f1,delimiter=':')
         for row in filetwo:
             if row[0] == 'suiteName':
                 return row[1]
```

After this I am confused and this is also giving error

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: Paste that in the question

Comment: I want to read a variable and replace the value of variable in other file

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [102]: with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
     ...:     f1_value = [i.strip().split("=")[1] for i in f1.readlines() if i.strip().split("=")[0] == "c"][0]
     ...:     f2_value = re.sub(r"suiteName: \"(.*)\"", "suiteName: \"{}\"".format(f1_value), f2.read())
     ...:     print(f2_value)
     ...:     with open("file2.txt","w") as f3:
     ...:         f3.write(f2_value)
     ...:
 override func broadcastStarted(withSetupInfo setupInfo: [String : NSObject]?) {

    if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "dddd.eeeee.fffff")
```

Comment: I wil not be aware about values in suiteName, its developer specific. without knowing the value of suitename I should replace with the variable in c

Comment: I have updated. It's replacing the file content too. Check once again